# Erreur running cordoba on IOS device

Tags: ios, meteor

When i’m running my web app on ios i have the following error message on my iPhone I get stuck as i cannot find how to solve the it:

Oops, looks like there’s no route on the client or the server for url: "http://localhost:12776/?cdvToken=D2A0142A-4AF5-4405-B52F-C940CB7274A2-19981-000004BE11E3B85A."

Many thanks for your help!

Olivier

Also please find the command run
            $ meteor run ios-device

```
        [[[[[ ~/project1 ]]]]]                     

        => Started proxy.                             
        => Started MongoDB.                           
        => Meteor 1.7.0.3 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
        WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.2.1, but it should have a minimum version of 2.3.0 to ensure
                 compatibility with the current platform versions. Installing the minimum version for convenience, but you should
                 adjust your dependencies.
        WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-splashscreen@4.0.1, but it should have a minimum version of 4.1.0 to
                 ensure compatibility with the current platform versions. Installing the minimum version for convenience, but you
                 should adjust your dependencies.

        WARNING: It looks like you are using OAuth2 login in your app. Meteor's OAuth2 implementation does not currently work with
                 mobile apps in local development mode, except in the iOS simulator. You can run the iOS simulator with 'meteor run
                 ios'. For additional workarounds, see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/OAuth-for-mobile-Meteor-clients.

        WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device. For the mobile app to be able to connect to the local server, make sure
                 your device is on the same network, and that the network configuration allows clients to talk to each other (no
                 client isolation).

        Your project has been opened in Xcode so that you can run your app on an iOS device. For further instructions, visit this wiki
        page: https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#running-on-ios

        => Started app on iOS Device.                 
        W20180617-18:49:14.060(2)? (STDERR) WARNING:  
        W20180617-18:49:14.132(2)? (STDERR) cfs:graphicsmagick could not find "graphicsMagic" or "imageMagic" on the
        W20180617-18:49:14.133(2)? (STDERR) system.
        W20180617-18:49:14.133(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:14.134(2)? (STDERR) I just checked PATH to see if I could find the GraphicsMagick or ImageMagic
        W20180617-18:49:14.134(2)? (STDERR) unix/mac os/windows binaries on your system, I failed.
        W20180617-18:49:14.134(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:14.134(2)? (STDERR) Why:
        W20180617-18:49:14.135(2)? (STDERR) 1. I may be blind or naive, help making me smarter
        W20180617-18:49:14.135(2)? (STDERR) 2. You havent added the path to the binaries
        W20180617-18:49:14.135(2)? (STDERR) 3. You havent actually installed GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick
        W20180617-18:49:14.136(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:14.136(2)? (STDERR) *** Make sure "$PATH" environment is configured "PATH:/path/to/binaries" ***
        W20180617-18:49:14.136(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:14.137(2)? (STDERR) Installation hints:
        W20180617-18:49:14.137(2)? (STDERR) * Mac OS X "brew install graphicsmagick" or "brew install imagemagick"
        W20180617-18:49:14.137(2)? (STDERR) * Linux download rpm or use packagemanager
        W20180617-18:49:14.138(2)? (STDERR) * Centos "yum install GraphicsMagick"* Windows download the installer and run
        W20180617-18:49:14.527(2)? (STDERR) /Users/mymac/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.1_1.o8hqcq.5zvm++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
        W20180617-18:49:14.527(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
        W20180617-18:49:14.528(2)? (STDERR)                         ^
        W20180617-18:49:14.528(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:14.528(2)? (STDERR) Error: Already registered the facebook OAuth service
        W20180617-18:49:14.528(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.OAuth.registerService (packages/oauth.js:64:11)
        W20180617-18:49:14.529(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/facebook.js:38:7
        W20180617-18:49:14.530(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/facebook.js:136:4
        W20180617-18:49:14.530(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/facebook.js:140:4
        W20180617-18:49:14.531(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/facebook.js:148:3
        W20180617-18:49:14.531(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:411:36
        W20180617-18:49:14.531(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        W20180617-18:49:14.532(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:220:19
        W20180617-18:49:14.532(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:471:5
        W20180617-18:49:14.532(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
        W20180617-18:49:14.532(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:470:11
        => Exited with code: 1
        W20180617-18:49:20.164(2)? (STDERR) WARNING:  
        W20180617-18:49:20.165(2)? (STDERR) cfs:graphicsmagick could not find "graphicsMagic" or "imageMagic" on the
        W20180617-18:49:20.165(2)? (STDERR) system.
        W20180617-18:49:20.166(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:20.166(2)? (STDERR) I just checked PATH to see if I could find the GraphicsMagick or ImageMagic
        W20180617-18:49:20.166(2)? (STDERR) unix/mac os/windows binaries on your system, I failed.
        W20180617-18:49:20.167(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:20.167(2)? (STDERR) Why:
        W20180617-18:49:20.167(2)? (STDERR) 1. I may be blind or naive, help making me smarter
        W20180617-18:49:20.168(2)? (STDERR) 2. You havent added the path to the binaries
        W20180617-18:49:20.168(2)? (STDERR) 3. You havent actually installed GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick
        W20180617-18:49:20.168(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:20.168(2)? (STDERR) *** Make sure "$PATH" environment is configured "PATH:/path/to/binaries" ***
        W20180617-18:49:20.169(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:20.169(2)? (STDERR) Installation hints:
        W20180617-18:49:20.169(2)? (STDERR) * Mac OS X "brew install graphicsmagick" or "brew install imagemagick"
        W20180617-18:49:20.170(2)? (STDERR) * Linux download rpm or use packagemanager
        W20180617-18:49:20.170(2)? (STDERR) * Centos "yum install GraphicsMagick"* Windows download the installer and run
        W20180617-18:49:20.597(2)? (STDERR) /Users/mymac/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.1_1.o8hqcq.5zvm++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
        W20180617-18:49:20.598(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
        W20180617-18:49:20.598(2)? (STDERR)                         ^
        W20180617-18:49:20.598(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:20.598(2)? (STDERR) Error: Already registered the facebook OAuth service
        W20180617-18:49:20.599(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.OAuth.registerService (packages/oauth.js:64:11)
        W20180617-18:49:20.599(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/facebook.js:38:7
        W20180617-18:49:20.599(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/facebook.js:136:4
        W20180617-18:49:20.599(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/facebook.js:140:4
        W20180617-18:49:20.600(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/facebook.js:148:3
        W20180617-18:49:20.600(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:411:36
        W20180617-18:49:20.600(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        W20180617-18:49:20.600(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:220:19
        W20180617-18:49:20.601(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:471:5
        W20180617-18:49:20.601(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
        W20180617-18:49:20.601(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:470:11
        => Exited with code: 1
        W20180617-18:49:26.497(2)? (STDERR) WARNING:  
        W20180617-18:49:26.498(2)? (STDERR) cfs:graphicsmagick could not find "graphicsMagic" or "imageMagic" on the
        W20180617-18:49:26.498(2)? (STDERR) system.
        W20180617-18:49:26.499(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:26.499(2)? (STDERR) I just checked PATH to see if I could find the GraphicsMagick or ImageMagic
        W20180617-18:49:26.499(2)? (STDERR) unix/mac os/windows binaries on your system, I failed.
        W20180617-18:49:26.500(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:26.500(2)? (STDERR) Why:
        W20180617-18:49:26.501(2)? (STDERR) 1. I may be blind or naive, help making me smarter
        W20180617-18:49:26.501(2)? (STDERR) 2. You havent added the path to the binaries
        W20180617-18:49:26.501(2)? (STDERR) 3. You havent actually installed GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick
        W20180617-18:49:26.502(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:26.503(2)? (STDERR) *** Make sure "$PATH" environment is configured "PATH:/path/to/binaries" ***
        W20180617-18:49:26.503(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:26.503(2)? (STDERR) Installation hints:
        W20180617-18:49:26.504(2)? (STDERR) * Mac OS X "brew install graphicsmagick" or "brew install imagemagick"
        W20180617-18:49:26.504(2)? (STDERR) * Linux download rpm or use packagemanager
        W20180617-18:49:26.504(2)? (STDERR) * Centos "yum install GraphicsMagick"* Windows download the installer and run
        W20180617-18:49:27.346(2)? (STDERR) /Users/mymac/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.1_1.o8hqcq.5zvm++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
        W20180617-18:49:27.347(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
        W20180617-18:49:27.347(2)? (STDERR)                         ^
        W20180617-18:49:27.347(2)? (STDERR) 
        W20180617-18:49:27.348(2)? (STDERR) Error: Already registered the facebook OAuth service
        W20180617-18:49:27.348(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.OAuth.registerService (packages/oauth.js:64:11)
        W20180617-18:49:27.348(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/facebook.js:38:7
        W20180617-18:49:27.348(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/facebook.js:136:4
        W20180617-18:49:27.348(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/facebook.js:140:4
        W20180617-18:49:27.349(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/facebook.js:148:3
        W20180617-18:49:27.349(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:411:36
        W20180617-18:49:27.349(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        W20180617-18:49:27.349(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:220:19
        W20180617-18:49:27.349(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:471:5
        W20180617-18:49:27.350(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
        W20180617-18:49:27.350(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/mymac/project1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:470:11
        => Exited with code: 1
        => Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Safari console his showing me the following error:

```
        [Error] Origin http://localhost:12776 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
        [Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:12776 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (info, line 0)
        [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.108:3000/sockjs/info?cb=9_5dgq9so9 due to access control checks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Local mobile development needs to be started with this command: `NODE_ENV=development meteor run ios-device`

Comment: Still have the same error Oops, looks like there’s no route on the client or the server for url: "http://localhost:12776/?cdvToken=D2A0142A-4AF5-4405-B52F-C940CB7274A2-19981-000004BE11E3B85A."